# An COTS solution for delaying a 120kHz analog signal?

Tags: analog, delay

Looking for some cheap method of adding a 350uS delay to a pulsed sine wave. It would be useful to emulate a pitch-catch ultrasonic distance measurement setup

Comment: You mean like a delay line?

Comment: "COTS solution" means that this is a shopping question, which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

It's a job interview question :) The cheapest available solution is a microcontroller with ADC and DAC. 240kHz is a little fast, but feasible. So you just sample the input signal, store it in the memory, and then put it on output with programmable delay.

Comment: Could use a <$2 MK02FN64VFM10 which has 1.2MSPS 12-bit ADC and 12-bit DAC on-chip 16k x 8 RAM which is sufficient for ~6ms delay at 1.2 MBS without packing, and ~9ms packing 2 x 12 bits into 3 bytes. Of course a bit of code would be required.

Comment: And if I put that together, and costed my company time, it would be around $2000 excluding parts and PCB layout and manufacture. Let's say an even $3000. Hence the question.

Comment: @DirkBruere: What Dave Tweed said...

Answer (score 0):

Run the pulse through about 53cm of distilled water at 25C.

Comment: I already run it through air. I am looking for something to emulate the mechanical bits ie transducers, housing etc.